# prove or disprove that a function is surjective, injective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$f:P(\mathbb{R})\times P(\mathbb{R})\to P(\mathbb{R})\\
f(X,Y)= X\cap Y\\
$

1. prove or disprove that a function is injective
2. prove or disprove that a function is surjective

for example f not injective because $ f(\{1,2\}, \{2,3\})=f(\{2,4\}, \{2,5\})=\{2\} $ but $(\{1,2\}, \{2,3\})\ne (\{2,4\}, \{2,5\})$

Comment: perhaps you mean $\mathbb{R}$ ( mathbb{R})?

Comment: What is preventing you from accomplishing this on your own without help?  Do you understand what is being asked?  Have you seen any other examples of proving a function to be injective or surjective?

Comment: @hehelego irrelevant.  The function $f~:~\mathcal{P}(A)\times\mathcal{P}(A)\to\mathcal{P}(A)$ would be just as valid to talk about and the proof will be the same regardless what $A$ happened to be for both parts (*so long as $A\neq \emptyset$*)

Comment: As for hints... $\{1,2,3\}\cap \{1,2,3\}=\{1,2,3\}$.  Also $\{1,2,3\}\cap\{1\}=\{1\}\cap\{1,2,3\}$

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks for correction. I am sorry that I had posted this comment without much consideration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. set intersection is a commutative operator, so the function $f$ is not injective.
2. $f$ is surjective, $\forall S\subseteq R\ f(S,{R})=S\cap{R}=S$

Comment: thanks for your answer @hehelego, but how does this prove that $\forall Z\in P(\mathbb{R})\exists(X, Y)\in P(\mathbb{R})\times P(\mathbb{R}):f(X, Y)=Z $

Comment: @DavidSergeev very simply by setting $X=Z$ and $Y=\Bbb R$.  You have that $f(Z,\Bbb R) = Z\cap \Bbb R = Z$